# Getting safe user input in python

Tags: python, input, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a script that needs some very simple input from the user, and upon doing my research on this I am in a dilemma trying to work out the safest way to do it.

I only want an integer and stumbled across (what I thought was) a nice piece of code similar to (doing this from memory):

```
def getNumeric(prompt):
  while True:
    response = input(prompt)
    try:
      return int(response)
    except ValueError:
      print "please enter a number:",
```

This mostly worked, but if the user just pressed [enter] then it crashed. Turns out, I'm using python < 3, and the author wrote this for 3+. So now I have to rewrite for 2.7 to suit my needs. But how do I write it to cater for EITHER platform <3 and 3+?

I am writing something that could be used by others and want to make it the most portable I can. Should I bother?

As an aside, I am doing this for the Raspberry Pi, should I upgrade my python to 3, or leave it where it is (2.7.3)?

Comment: try changing 'input(prompt)' to 'raw_input(prompt)'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is to upgrade the Pi to Python 3. There's no point developing Python code for two separate versions (unless it's a library, which you'd use much more precautions than just sharing functions). You can do:

```
# Python 3.x
def getNumeric(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            res = int(input(prompt))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Numbers only please!")
    return res
```

For Python 2.7.x, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. `input()` in Python 2 is not considered save since it evaluates the string given (and can be malicious).

Comment: Text and Numbers work great, but in 2.7 (3 untested), if the user hits enter without any input I get:

Comment: `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: fixed (in 2.7) if I use `raw_input`. Thanks

Comment: The command `input()` is **not safe in Python 2**, because it evaluates the input string. It can also create a new program or run any program. It is not worse than an access to the console, but unsafe e.g. if the input is redirected remotely. An example of input `__import__('os').system('sh')`

Comment: @hynekcer Yea agreed, I'm going to change this (almost) 7 year old answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def getNumeric(prompt):
  while True:
    response = input(prompt)
    try:
      if isinstance(response, int):
          return int(response)
      else:
          print "please enter a number:"
    except ValueError:
      print "please enter a number:"
```